# VBA to download csv file from a website with login and password

Tags: vba, authentication, excel, csv, winhttprequest

Ole Henrik Skogstrøm kindly posted a reply in the thread: "How do i download a file using VBA (Without internet explorer)".

Have used his code as I wish to download a csv file from www.ft.com and save it to the temp file on my c drive. It is not that often I need to do this, so I decided to use simple excel VBA. I have set up a temporary test subscription account at www.FT.com to illustrate what I would like to download, username is "ft.testing.acct@gmail.com" password is "fttestpassword".

After logging in, the "export data" link can be seen in the top right hand side of the page:

http://portfolio.ft.com/holdings/overview/3415c458-40bf-4e63-903a-37302a88bd83?popout=true&..wsod..=off

The url passed when you click this link is:

http://portfolio.ft.com/PortfolioAPI/ExportToCSV?containerID=3415c458-40bf-4e63-903a-37302a88bd83&type=Holdings&customName=suggested__0YourPortfolio&duration=15&startDate=undefined&endDate=undefined

The following code returns a file, but this file just has "{"json":{"triggerLogin":true}}" in it.

```
Sub downloadingpositions()
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://portfolio.ft.com/PortfolioAPI/ExportToCSV?containerID=3415c458-40bf-4e63-903a-37302a88bd83&type=Holdings&customName=suggested__0YourPortfolio&duration=15&startDate=undefined&endDate=undefined"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "ft.testing.acct@gmail.com", "fttestpasword"
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
oStream.SaveToFile "c:\temp\testing.csv ", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
oStream.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I'm not getting logged in/ not getting the full csv file??

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, i.e. use VBA/Excel to login to www.ft.com to download market data. The above code doesn't seem to work at all as logging in to ft.com has changed. You don't have anything more up-to-date by any chance?

Comment: Hi, haven’t done this for a long while, but it does seems that the base url has changed as per: https://developer.ft.com/portal/docs-api-reference . good luck 

Comment: Thank you, but this requires a license to be bought to use the API. Was hoping to avoid that as all I want is an easy way to get a portfolio into a spreadsheet, which unfortunately requires Excel/VBA to login to ft.com.

Comment: I’ll see if I can take a look at it today, but in the meantime have you considered Quandl? https://www.quandl.com/tools/api

Comment: Never seen that site and it looks pretty amazing. The trouble is, like most data providers e.g. yahoo finance, google finance, is that they don't have the variety of prices that ft.com has. E.g. they don't have UK mutual funds, and in the case of Quandl, UK stocks require a premium account. Hence I am trying to automate access to ft.com. Ive had some success with copying and pasting web pages into excel (via VBA) but it isn't a great way to do it...

Comment: FWIW www.morningstar.co.uk is also pretty good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I noticed about your code is that the password was missing an "s". Then when you have a strange long number in the url is because there is some kind of authentication needed to generate the url "3415c458-40bf-4e63-903a-37302a88bd83"

When this happens you need to locate the signin url and then use a "POST" method to validate the data. Once you have done that then you can send the regular "GET" request and the data will show.

```
Sub downloadingpositions()

    Const strLOGING_URL As String = "https://registration.ft.com/registration/barrier/login?username=ft.testing.acct@gmail.com&password=fttestpassword"
    Const strPORTFOLIO_URL As String = "http://portfolio.ft.com/PortfolioAPI/ExportToCSV?containerID=3415c458-40bf-4e63-903a-37302a88bd83&type=Holdings&customName=suggested__0YourPortfolio&duration=15&startDate=undefined&endDate=undefined"
    Const strINCORRECT_CREDENTIALS As String = "Your email address and password do not match our records"
    Const strFILE_NAME As String = "c:\temp\testing.csv"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim oStream As Object

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    ' Post to the url to set the credentials
    WinHttpReq.Open "POST", strLOGING_URL, 0
    WinHttpReq.Send


    ' Make sure authetication went through
    If Not UCase$(WinHttpReq.ResponseText) Like "*" & UCase$(strINCORRECT_CREDENTIALS) & "*" Then

        ' Get the information.
        WinHttpReq.Open "GET", strPORTFOLIO_URL, 0
        WinHttpReq.Send

        ' If we have succedeed then write the response to the file.
        If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
            oStream.SaveToFile strFILE_NAME, 2    ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox strINCORRECT_CREDENTIALS, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope this helps :)